# LAN7515 replacement USB controller chip

Tags: pi-3b+

a defective video cable shorted pin 1 + 2 of GPIO shortening QFN regulator MXL7704-03. Replaced and WORKING but

LAN7515 which has built-in USB controller had fried too and USBs DONT WORK!!! i DONT mind if RJ45 does not work ANYMORE.
But I need the USBs WORKING again. LAN7515 is not for sale.

Need ANY COMPATIBLE chip that makes USB work even if it does not have built in network driver.
WHICH CHIP???? I need a chip that makes that, i dont care if I have to join it to BGA with wires!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found those chips on AliExpress today. Not cheap, but they’re available. Or you may get one from a dead Raspberry Pi.

My only question is does that same chip also provide HDMI output on the Pi? Because I have some with a dead HDMI and some with dead USB/Ethernet